# Iterating through a data file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm new to bash and unfamiliar. I'm attempting to move through a file with data separated by a space and ","and store information into a list. The only container bash seems to have is an array. Any help with this is appreciated.

Say I have a file titled sample.txt with usernames passwords and birthrates and wanted to iterate through and store the users, passwords and birthdate in separate lists, what would be the easiest way to accomplish this

sample.txt

```
user1, password1, 081192
user2, password2, 092578
user3, password3, 020564
```

Comment: By "separate lists" do you mean arrays? Do you mean files? What are you going to need to *do* with these "lists"?

Comment: `bash` is probably not the right language for this.

Comment: @EtanReisner any type of container is fine. It seems that arrays are the only container used in bash. I haven't been able to find others. The only issue is arrays have to have a predetermined size. I don't know if this applies in bash.

Comment: No, bash arrays are not predetermined. The real question, which you didn't answer, is what are you going to *do* with these "lists" once you have them? Are they just getting written to files? Are they being manipulated? Do you need to relate the entry in one list to the entry in another list? Do you actually need lists here at all or do you just need to to serially process the data? Ask your **actual** question instead of the question you think you are stuck at.

Comment: @EtanReisner For each userData in userDataList
        Extract user name, password and Birthdate
        Create unix command to update password for that useName
        Create unix command to update expire date for that user name
        Printout that user updated information to the terminal 
End of loop
close file if necessary

Comment: So that's serial processing then if you can do those jobs as you go? That's a very different question then. I would update your question to ask **that** question since you will get many simpler and more direct answers to your *actual* problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Bash version 4 has associative arrays, which is what I think you're looking for.

Be warned, you require a lot of noisy syntax (braces, brackets and quotes) to work with arrays in bash.

```
IFS+=","          # add comma to the list of characters for word splitting
                  # you now cannot use a comma in your passwords.

declare -A passwords ids           # 2 associative arrays

while read -r user password id; do
    passwords["$user"]=$password
    ids["$user"]=$id
done < sample.txt

# now that they are stored, let's print them out:
# iterate over the keys of the ids array
for user in "${!ids[@]}"; do
    printf "%s:%s:%s\n" "$user" "${passwords["$user"]}" "${ids["$user"]}"
done
```

I'll provide some links to documentation in the bash manual: it is very dense reading, but is the source of wisdom for bash.

- the [read](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) command
- how the shell splits text into words, using the IFS variable: [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)

  - and the order of shell expansions is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)
- bash [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. For some reason, it isn't outputting the arrays. But, this was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure bashisms for this like so:

```
# read a csv line by line and fill an array
# called "myArray" with values from somefile.csv
while IFS=$',' read -r -a myArray; do
    echo "${myArray[0]}"
    echo "${myArray[1]}"
    echo "${myArray[2]}"
done < somefile.csv
```

Example output:

```
foo
bar
baz
tum
di
dum
```

Example somefile.csv:

```
foo,bar,baz
tum,di,dum
```

Comment: The useless use of `cat` creates a subshell in which the value of `line` is set.

Comment: @chepner The `cat` doesn't actually cause the problem, it's the pipe. You could use process sub and still uselessly use cat.

Comment: Ah yes of course.. coffee deficiency detected. Fixed!

Comment: This works, but the scope is only inside the while lop. When I tried to declare it outside the while loop, it did not work. Also, do you thing it would be wise to do it with an associat